# Ruby: How to print strings from arrays in parallel

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have 3 arrays and I'm trying to print the respective strings in parallel. Very new to Ruby. Not sure if I should be concatenating? I'd really like to create a table, but I have no idea how.

My current code:

```
name = ["Buffy Summers", "Willow Rosenberg", "Xander Harris"]
age = ["17", "16", "18"]
hair_color = ["blonde", "red", "brown"]

print name[0]
print " "
print age[0] 
print " "
puts hair_color[0]

print name[1]
print " "
print age[1] 
print " "
puts hair_color[1]

print name[2]
print " "
print age[2] 
print " "
puts hair_color[2]
```

Output looks like this:

```
Buffy Summers 17 Blonde
Willow Rosenberg 16 Red
Xander Harris 18 Brown
```

I'd really like them to align. I realize that I also should be looping. I'm a beginner.

I want the output to read:

```
Buffy Summers    17  Blonde
Willow Rosenberg 16  Red
Xander Harris    18  Brown
```

Comment: What code do you currently have, and how is it deficient?

Comment: Edited for clarity. @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the aligning as you want, more information at [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-25).

```
max = name.group_by(&:length).max.first

name.zip(age, hair_color).each do |name, age, hair_color|
  puts "%-#{max}s %s %s" % [name, age, hair_color]
end

=> Buffy Summers    17 blonde
=> Willow Rosenberg 16 red
=> Xander Harris    18 brown
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data were contained in the following four arrays.

```
name       = ["Buffy Summers", "Willow Rosenberg", "Xander Harris", "Granny", "Lucy"]
age        = ["17", "16", "18", "101", "7"]
hair_color = ["blonde", "red", "brown", "white", "purple"]    
col_fmt    = [{justify: :L, pad: 4}, {justify: :R, pad: 2}, {justify: :L, pad: 3}]
```

Then you could pretty-print as follows.

```
arr = [name, age, hair_color]
columns = col_fmt.zip(arr.map { |a| a.max_by(&:size).size }).
  map { |h, sz| h.merge(width: sz) }
  #=> [{:justify=>:L, :pad=>4, :width=>16}, {:justify=>:R, :pad=>2, :width=>3},
  #    {:justify=>:L, :pad=>3, :width=>6}] 
arr.transpose.each do |a|
  a.zip(columns).each do |attr, fmt|
    print ' ' * fmt[:pad]
    print fmt[:justify] == :L ? attr.ljust(fmt[:width]) : attr.rjust(fmt[:width])
  end
  puts
end
#     Buffy Summers      17   blonde
#     Willow Rosenberg   16   red   
#     Xander Harris      18   brown 
#     Granny            101   white 
#     Lucy                7   purple
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do following

```
name = ["Buffy Summers", "Willow Rosenberg", "Xander Harris"]
age = ["17", "16", "18"]
hair_color = ["blonde", "red", "brown"]
```

<del>name.count.times do |index|</del>
<del>puts "#{name[index]} #{age[index]} #{hair_color[index]}"</del>
<del>end</del>

```
name.count.times do |index|
  printf "%-20s %-2s %-10s\n", name[index],age[index] , hair_color[index]
end
```

Comment: These columns don't align.

Comment: Replace second last line with following 
printf "%-20s %-2s %-10s\n", name[index],age[index] , hair_color[index]